# Avoid warning: unreferenced find_rule label

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

In order To get more compatibility between flex and other version of lex , we should add `-l` option in flex command.
One of these incompatibilities is `yylineno` (global variable to store line number). Although there are two ways to activate this option :

- using %option yylineno
- or -l option

I have always this kind of warning :

> warning C4102: 'find_rule' : unreferenced label

any help please to avoid this warning!

Comment: This link may help [C4102](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dec9tw1t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: in fact, the code where the warning is referenced is auto generated from the flex code,so i cant delete this label.

Comment: Specify `/wd4102` as compiler switch will disable the warning.

Comment: Is the code in a .h file or in a .cpp file?

Comment: @sharptooth the code is in .c file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say that the code triggering the warning is auto-generated and can't be controlled by you, the only way to get rid of the warning is to suppress it for that code only. You have two options.

Option one is to alter the compiler settings for the specific file (not the best thing to maintain).

Option 2 is to `#include` the .c file into another file and wrap that into `#pragma warning`:

```
//WrapperGateFile.c
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4102)

#include "ProblematicFile.c"

#pragma warning(pop)
```

and (important!) either not include the problematic .c file into the project or exclude the original .c file from build ("Excluded from build" property) so that it is not compiled and linked twice.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description from [C4102](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dec9tw1t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the cause is an unreferenced label:

```
int f()
{
    test: // This will produce C4102

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

To prevent the warning you can remove the unused label or disable the warning by either modifying the source:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4102)
void f()
{
    test: // This will produce C4102

    return;
}
#pragma warning(pop)
```

or by specifying `/wd4102` as a compiler switch.

As you state this is generated code which you do not wish to change the compiler switch is the only option (I can think of).

Comment: Since it is a Visual C++ specific question I guess `__noop()` intrinsic should be better than `return`.

Comment: @sharptooth, ok (never used that before).